# Nice Menus drupal module not working in Firefox after after module is moved to /all/modules

Tags: javascript, css, drupal

i am currently cleaning up a messy drupal site that i will have to administer in the coming months.
My first move was to move all custom modules to /sites/all/modules

In all browsers this causes no issues, except firefox.
The Menus render correctly but do not accept mouse-input ...
When i copy the module back to /modules/ all is fine again.

I checked all the source files for hidden hard-coded references but could not find anything.

Maybe someone can get me started on where to look for solutions next?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: If Firefox is your default browser you might want to clear the browser cache as well. If other browsers work fine, it is probably a local issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the system table after moving a module to a new directory. The best way to do this is `drush rr` You'll need to install [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) and [registry_rebuild](http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) modules on your system but it will rapidly rewrite your system table to match the new file structure. You should also be able to rebuild the system table by just visiting the /modules page.